# how can i manage that context id remain same for the session of the user

Tags: node.js, botframework

```
 var context id="";
```

i declare this context id outside my bot.dialoge to save the context id of my user but it become same for all the users how can i manage that context id remain same for the session of the user

```
       bot.dialog('/', [ 
     function (session) {   
       var question=session.message.text;
      session.send(question);
      var id="";

      var request = require('request'),
      url="https://api.projectoxford.ai/luis/v2.0/apps/76c-4784-a26d-b?         subscription-key=15f282c1&q=";

var url1=url+question;


url1+="&contextId=";

url1+=contextId ;//complete url to request with context id;
session.send(" i am here i function %s",url1);
session.send(" i am sessionid %s",session.id );

   var luis_question=""//variable question generated by luis api;
  request({
   url: url1,
  json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {

  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) 
  {
  if(body.topScoringIntent.intent!="None")
 {
 session.send( "i am in intent %s",body.topScoringIntent.intent);
 session.id=body.dialog.contextId;
 session.send("i am in prompt %s",session.id);
```

i am getting context id from here
          contextId=body.dialog.contextId;
         session.send('addres"%s"',session.message.address);

```
    session.send(" %s",body.dialog.prompt); 
    session.send(" %s",body.dialog.status); 
   if(body.dialog.status=="Finished")
     {      
      contextId ="";
      session.send(" Thanks for co operation");

       }
     }
  else
      session.send(" Please ask relevant question");
     /*  session.send( body.dialog.status);
     session.send("i am in prompt %s",body.entities[0].entity); */  
      }

      }
      ) 
   }

     ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you are trying to accomplish, but to store user specific data use the SDK’s built-in storage system.

To save data:

```
session.userData.{fieldName} = {value};
```

To retrieve:

```
session.userData.{fieldName}
```

Note this is limited to 32k.  Example [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/guides/core-concepts/#adding-dialogs-and-memory).

Comment: i want to store the context id for each user and want that it should remain same for user when ever it starts again tallking with bot

Comment: for your help exactly that was needed

Comment: session.userData.fieldName